# Drupal 7 Module not showing up in list

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have created a module called custom_views. Its directory is: `sites/all/modules/custom_views`

In the directory there are two files called:

```
custom_views.info
```

and

```
custom_views.module
```

Here is the code for the `.info` file:

```
; Custom views created by me
name = Custom Views
description = Module to allow custom view development
package = Custom Views
core = 7.x
php = 5.2
```

Here is the code for the `.module` file:

```
<?php
  function custom-views_views_default_views() {
  $views = array();
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_views') . '/views';
  $files = drupal_system_listing('.inc$', $path, 'name', 0);
  foreach($files as $file) {
  include_once $file->filename;
  }
return $views;
}
?>
```

For some reason it will not allow me to enable it in the modules list and I cannot figure out why... I have also tried `clearing my cache`. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Try custom_views_views_default_views() instead of custom-views_views_default_views()

Comment: Are there any errors in the apache/php logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function name is wrong as mentioned in other answers. The hyphen should be replaced with an underscore.

**Double check the module location**

It should reside in one of the following folders

- /sites/all/modules/your_module
- /sites/domain.com/modules/your_module
- /sites/all/modules/your_module

**Info File**

Only Name, Description and Core are required in your info file. Start by removing everything except those values.

```
name = Custom Views
description = Module to allow custom view development
core = 7.x
```

The PHP version you specified is a minimum PHP version required to run the module. Sounds obvious but have you checked to see if you are running >= 5.2

**Check the permissions of the module folder and the `.info` file too.**

When Drupal looks for modules, it uses `file_exists()` on the .info file which will return false if the file does not exist, or it cannot access it due to permissions or incorrect ownership.

The ownership of the file is of key importance too. Check the owner of the info file matches one of a module which works.

**Encoding**

Some encoding can prevent the .info file being read. UTF8 without BOM should typically be read successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the long right up. After fist look, I was sure that you would have something in here to help my issue. Unfortunately, I tried all of your suggestions including rewriting the whole module and nothing seemed to work. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Try stripping your module back to complete basics. Just the folder and .info file. Also, try renaming your module after you've tried that- it's possible that it's clashing with something, perhaps a module or a sub module inside another module.

Comment: I honestly am not sure. Something must have been hanging up in the cache and for whatever reason, removing everything and starting from scratch with only the necessities seemed to work for me.

Comment: @BenSwinburne, tried your steps and module started in showing. PS: I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 1):

Follow documentation here

https://drupal.org/node/1075072

where you see you should have your well-written module even without the .module file

have fun!

Comment: thanks for the help... unfortunately that did not help me. I'll keep looking. In the mean time, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: check your web server error log. Example:                                  tail -f /var/log/apache2/error*

Comment: .info files are .ini syntax. `;` is the right notation for commented lines

Comment: @augusto - where is the log file for drupal located?

Comment: @scapegoat17, you'll find more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421188/how-can-i-check-drupal-log-files

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will help your module to appear on the module page, but I think your function should be called custom_views_views_default_views() rather than custom-views_views_default_views()

i.e. underscore not dash in function name

Maybe Drupal only lists modules with at least one valid function

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tried all the other suggested issues, try removing the closing php tag.

Not sure if it would be causing your particular problem but it is recommended you don't use closing php tags in your module files as you can run into problems if there is whitespace after the closing tag.

There could also possibly be problems with the other files you are including.

What if you comment out the function you have in the .module file and try to install it.
If it works then you have a problem in that function or in the files it includes.