# Destination directory is not properly configured for Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I keep getting the error on my Drupal 7 site - even after I have configured the logging and errrors to 'none'

I have made my tmp file writeable 777 and checked the file directory is correct under 'file system' I have made my sites/default/files directory writeable also

Cannot seem to get rid of this error - it reads:

The specified file temporary://fileg2e71m could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the system log say?

Comment: Where can I find the system log?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421188/how-can-i-check-drupal-log-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have resolved the issue:

It was an ownership issue where the files are owned by the Apache user. I Set PHP 5 to run in cgi-mode on my cPanel.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 and drupal 8 and 9:
After importing a Database, some paths are not quite well defined. Go to /admin/config/media/file-system and hit "Save Configuration". Now the Translations-import works fine.