# currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7. I get this error when I change the pagination offset. I thought it was a memory issue so I increased PHP memory limit but that didn't work.

It doesn't happen on all the pages. It happens on page 2.

The pages are created with a paginated view.

http://s***.build.us.*****.net/ko/learning-center/blog?page=2 //this doesn't work

but not on page 3

http://s***.build.us.*****.net/ko/learning-center/blog?page=3 . //this works

There is nothing useful in the apache access or the error log

When I use drush I get the following

```
Command watchdog-show needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run this command.                                                               [error]
The drush command 'watchdog-show' could not be executed.
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message.

Comment: I'm getting 10.103.60.249 - preview [21/Aug/2018:15:49:15 +0000] "GET /ko/learning-center/blog?page=2 HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36

Comment: That's the access log. You need to check the error log.

Comment: there is nothing recorded in the error log

Comment: Drupal might have it's own error logs. You may want to check there as well.

Comment: I can't find the location of the drupal error log

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421188/how-can-i-check-drupal-log-files

Comment: i have used drush and got the following error -- in the updated question

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 means there was a Fatal Error in a PHP script. You could try to check Drupal Log files. It could be a bug with Drupal itself.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was mysql

i had to increase the mysql config directive

mysql `max_allowed_packet` to something higher